# NextJS App Router with typescript will either let me use react-bootstrap or my global.scss file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, sass, react-bootstrap

I've tried reading through documentation for App Router and React-Bootstrap package and when I try to import react bootstrap it completely removes my global.scss file rulesets, but when I remove the react bootstrap import it uses the global.scss file

It works in one of my other projects that uses all the same dependencies but not this one? I tried to cross reference to see if there was anything different in setup but I can't find anything

Please note I tried the JS and CSS bootstrap imports and only the css one works

```
import '@styles/globals.scss';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
// Components
import Navigation from '@components/Navigation';
import Footer from '@components/Footer';
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

const DynamicBootstrap = dynamic(
  () => require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'),
  { ssr: false }
);
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This code is in my global layout.tsx file

Here is my package list:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.4.5",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/node": "20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.8",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.32",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "animejs": "^3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.4",
    "swr": "^2.1.5",
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-cmd": "^5.0.0",
    "node-ssh": "^13.1.0"
  }
```

Here is my tsconfig.json in case this helps:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "@components/*": [
        "./src/components/*"
      ],
      "@styles/*": [
        "./src/styles/*"
      ],
      "@assets/*": [
        "./src/assets/*"
      ],
      "@middlewares/*": [
        "./src/middlewares/*"
      ],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess when you try to import it in the layout.tsx file it overwrites, so after reading more of the react bootstrap documentation. You can add

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

to your globals stylesheet file and it imports it normally letting me be able to use my global styles and react bootstrap